# Log retention policy in Galaxybase graph database

Tags: graph-databases

As I was going through the logs of Galaxybase usage in September, I realised that the logs from that time were gone.  I am curious about the strategy employed for storing and retaining log information. I would like to know how long the logs are kept and if there is any compression or archival mechanism in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galaxybase will pack and compress based on date and log size, retaining for a duration of one month.